# Resolving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to learn spring. So I typed up this project but on running it it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:145)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:84)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:58)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at maven.spring.trial.App.main(App.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 12 more
```

I have tried many solutions given on SO already, like adding commons-logging, via maven, downloading the jar and adding it to my external Libraries.

This is a screenshot of my tree structure-

[image]

My Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringExamples</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SpringExamples</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I am running the project from my App.java

Can someone help me with this??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this application on servlet container or application servlet that already provides commons-logging library then you should change scope compile to provided. It looks like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Whereas you should change it such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When you build your application on maven, this library will be packaged together with other library in war file. Then this problem is resolved

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

The JARs you have added in your maven `pom` are available are available only during compile time.

But you also need those jars during runtime (run as main program) as well.

`NoClassDefFoundError` comes when your `class` is NOT available in the classpath during runtime. So add those JAR files to the Runtime classpath.

You can look at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-jar-application.html) to configure the JARs in Intellij.